# Combining Vue.js app and Restful API service

Tags: node.js, rest, express, vue.js

Is it possible to combine a Vue.js app with a restful API service?

New to Vue but written my first Vue/Typescript  app that is a front end that consumes some public APIs,  add extra logic and display results. All works – fine.  Now I also want to have my own restful API interface.

I know Vue apps are SPAs, so when I ‘change page’ to myapp.com/page2, it is not fetched from the sever but rather the app just re-renders the display.   But is it possible for those routes that are not defined, such as myapp.com/api/whatever, to be a restful interface? That is, consumes requests and return responses? And when hoisted, would a user have access to both a front-end and a back-end, even though the app is running client side?

Did start down this route using express.js but ran into issues as if I was trying to combine chalk and cheese. (Not lease, would need to change the node module to ‘commonJs’).

Would using Nuxt help? Know nothing about Nuxt … yet. Or must I go the traditional way, and write a separate back-end and change my front end to consume it.

Comment: Yes, this is 100% possible. You don't need Nuxt, you just need to build out your API and have Vue make calls to it via HTTP (probably using something like Axios to keep it simple).